# How to specify layout for Joomla Category page linked from List All Categories page

Tags: joomla-2.5, category-blog

I have a Joomla! site that has several modules displaying on my home page. I specify that these modules should show up on my homepage layout using the Module Manager. Great.

I have a separate menu item called "Topics" which is a "List all Categories" page. It lists all my categories and the number of items in each category like:

- Category A (2)
- Category B (5)
- Category C (12)

What I want is when you click on a category it goes to a simple one or two column page (Article Layout) without all of my modules, which either lists a small intro about each article in that category, or just the headline for the articles in that category.

What is actually happening is when I click on the category it links to a page that looks exactly like the homepage - with the Home menu item highlighted and all of the modules showing.

I guess my question is, how to I modify or specify what the Category page (list of articles) should look/layout?

Thanks

Comment: Are u looking for programmatic solution? Or one which just requires the administration interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I changed the category of my Topics menu from the "Blog" category to my custom "Homepage blog" category this seemed to fix things. Why I don't know, but this is what fixed it. Is "Blog" a default category that always uses the same layout as Home?

Answer (score 0):

Simply when You create/edit a module on joomla,

**Extension>Modules>New/Edit**
There is a **Menu Assignment** section. [More info Here](https://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_assign_a_module_to_specific_pages%3F)

There You can Choose on which menu item You want to show/hide Your module.
Go to each of Your module You don't want to display and uncheak the menu item.

And If you want to change style of Your web page, you can create a new template and add a template to Your menu item: **Menu > Edit/New > Template Style** choose Your template

Answer (score 0):

My guess is for each of the modules showing, in their respective *Menu Assignment* tabs, you have *On All Pages* select.

For each one, change to *Only on pages select*.

Then click both the *none* links in the newly displayed HTML to ensure the modules are not assigned to display anywhere.

Now click the home page menu endpoint.  Repeat this for each of the modules displaying.  Once complete, when you navigate from the homepage using the Category links, the modules should be gone.

Hope this helps.